# How to do harvard style referencing using org-ref

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am writing a paper using spacemacs with it's org-mode to export to latex. I want to referencing using the (author, year) style for example if I had the following reference in my .bib file

```
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1710-03748,
 author    = {Trapit Bansal and
           Jakub Pachocki and
           Szymon Sidor and
           Ilya Sutskever and
           Igor Mordatch},
title     = {Emergent Complexity via Multi-Agent Competition},
journal   = {CoRR},
volume    = {abs/1710.03748},
year      = {2017},
url       = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03748},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
eprint    = {1710.03748},
timestamp = {Mon, 13 Aug 2018 16:47:04 +0200},
biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/journals/corr/abs-1710-03748},
bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

Is there a citation style I could use in the text so the ouput is something like

```
this is an example sentance(Bansal, 2017)
```

or do I need to find another tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the harvard package (http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/harvard.pdf). You can use it like this in your org-file:

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage{harvard}

see cite:DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1710-03748

bibliographystyle:agsm
bibliography:test.bib
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! and thanks for writing org-ref!