# Harvard style citation in org-mode, output problems

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

Trying to cite papers in Harvard style by using org-ref (scimax). I found two posts about it in this forum : [post#1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52479/how-do-you-create-an-org-ref-harvard-style-in-text-citation-with-a-page-number) and [post#2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45765/how-to-do-harvard-style-referencing-using-org-ref).

The problem that I am facing is that the output of .org file contains 1 or 2 citations in Harvard format and all others are in other format.

Could someone explain me the reason and a proper solution for that ?

My org file contains the following :

```
#+creator: Emacs 27.1 (Org mode 9.3.7)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[round]{natbib}
#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex
#+latex_header: \usepackage{harvard} 

Some content here ..... and some references [citep:Artetxe2017]. Some other references [cite:mikolov2013exploiting].

bibliographystyle:apalike
bibliography:./ref/references.bib
```

About the output:

The first reference is outputted properly but the next one is numeric; the only difference between two citations is the first one starts with a capital letter and the other does not. Is this the only problem ?

Comment: if you can provide references.bib we might have a better chance of figuring this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution. It is not automatic as C-c C-e but it works.

First of all, using biblatex as reference "engine" is better. The org file that I am using has the following lines for Harvard reference.

```
#+creator: Emacs 27.1 (Org mode 9.3.7)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \addbibresource{./ref/references.bib}


* Introduction
  ... inspired by /the noisy channel model/ of IT[fn:1](cite:shannon2001mathematical).


\newpage
\printbibliography

* Footnotes
 
[fn:1] information theory
```

Then in order to export it use C-c C-e, the org engine then automatically shows me the .tex version of the org file. I think latex inside emacs is configured to run BibTex instead of Biber. And Biblatex needs to use Biber. So inside the .tex file use C-c C-c then select biber. Then again press C-c C-c choose latex. Then references are given as expected.